# Display exceptions in mod_wsgi hosted cherrypy app

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy app with works fine on my local machine, but not on my server. If an exception is thrown in a request handler, I see the following message in my browser:

> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.

How can I tell cherrypy to display the exception? I see no log information in the appache log or somewhere else. I would expect some flag where I can say "DEBUG=True" or something like that. But I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're setting the environment configuration to either production, embedded or test_suite then automatically log.screen is set to False. Manually setting this to true will give you a full trace-back displayed on screen. Alternatively you'd have to start digging in your web server logs.